# Show another view with IBAction - XIB and Storyboard

Tags: cocoa-touch, xib, storyboard

I am using Storyboard successfully.  One screen isn't "empty", it has a class NotifierViewController.

This class has a .h,.m and XIB File.  The app runs wonderfully.

Now I need a button in the XIB File to link this view back to my Storyboard. Right now, I have to stop and restart the app to see the main view.

So in the IB I created a UIButton and a IBAction in the .h and .m file. But my code for the actions doesn't run.  I get a black screen only.

The view that is the "Initial View Controller" in my Storyboard has the Class ViewController (only .h and .m File)

What is wrong?

```
#import "NotifierViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

- (IBAction)home:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Button was tapped");
    // init & alloc - Replace with your custom view controllers initialization method (if applicabale)
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    [viewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    [ViewController release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)home:(id)sender 
{

    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController* initialHelpView = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

    initialHelpView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self presentModalViewController:initialHelpView animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't reinitialize and represent your main "root" view. If are you presenting this NotifierViewController is presented modally, you can just dismiss it:

```
- (IBAction)home:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:Yes];
}
```

If NotifierViewController isn't being presented modally, let me know how and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: The right answer for me is here : [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169930/uibutton-ibaction-link-from-a-rootview-to-mainview-in-storyboard[link]